# Сложение volatile - UB?

Tags: c++, volatile

Содержит ли следующая программа `UB`?

```
#include <iostream>

volatile int x;

int main() {
  std::cout << (x + x);
}
```

Comment: В связи с чем вообще возник подобный вопрос?

Comment: @älёxölüt хотел использовать в многопоточном приложении, но раз `UB` тут, то лучше не стоит

Comment: Читать одну и ту же переменную без какой-либо синхронизации просто довесив на неё `volatile`?

Comment: @älёxölüt да, примерно так

Comment: Если бы всё было так просто, то атомарные типы были бы не нужны.

Comment: Непонятна связь приведенного примера с многопоточностью.

Comment: Прежде чем использовать `volatile` в многопоточных приложениях, предлагаю прочитать [эту](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/10/15/parallel_world_p5.aspx) статью. Или хотя бы последний в ней раздел, который так и называется `volatile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, содержит. Несколько доступов к одному и тому же volatile объекту без упорядочения этих доступов (unsequenced access) - неопределенное поведение.

Доступ к volatile объектам испокон веков является частью *наблюдаемого поведения* (observable behavior) С++ программы. Поэтому доступ к volatile объекту (даже только на чтение) формально считается *побочным эффектом* (side effect) содержащего этот доступ выражения. А далее уже работает общая схема: наличие в выражении неупорядоченных побочных эффектов, воздействующих на один и тот же объект - это неопределенное поведение.

> **[n4659]**
>
> **4.6 Program execution [intro.execution]**
>
> **14** Reading an object designated by a volatile glvalue (6.10), modifying an object, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.[...]
>
> **17** [...]If a side effect on a memory location (4.4) is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same memory location or a value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location, and they are not potentially concurrent (4.7), the behavior is undefined.[...]

В новой структуре документа:
http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-7
http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-10